# Gmail API: Fetching SPAM banner warning text

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

If you access Gmail via their web-client, and go to your spam box, you see all emails that have been assigned the label SPAM. However, upon clicking on such an email, the web-client also displays a banner at the top of the email, explaining why the email was labelled as SPAM. This banner is often grey or red colored.

I am looking for a way to fetch this banner's text via the API. Fetching labels is trivial, but it appears this banner is not stored as a label in any way. Just a mention or link to an API method would be much appreciated.

I could also do this via manual scraping with selenium and python, but it seems tedious.